# swap object files inside a library

Tags: c++, c, linker, cmake

In our project that we manage using cmake we use a static library lib.a
when linking.

So the final executable (statically linked) will be made of the object files that we have just compiled

`a.o`

`b.o`

`c.o`

and the static library
`lib.a`

However, it is possible (not always) that some of those files (let's say `c.o`) was already in lib.a. In this case, we would like to use the newest `c.o` that we have just compiled and not the one that was already in lib.a

Is this possible and how can we do that with Cmake?

What I thought was like un-archiving the lib.a, finding out whether any of the object files was already inside and archiving it again (using the `c.o` in this case), then linking normally the executable using

`a.o`

`b.o`

and the newly made

`lib.a`

Comment: In our case we normally compile and repackage all the libraries which have the instance of this updated library

Comment: @yanivx Well this is not possible for us, as we would like to only provide part of the source files to the users. The users might modify and recompile those files but they won't be able to recompile the whole lib.a.

Comment: I'd supply two libraries, one precompiled and the other one as source code.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux: `$ ar -ru lib.a c.o` should do. This will update `c.o` in `lib.a` provided that `c.o` is newer than the copy already included in `lib.a`.

From `$ man ar`:

> Normally, ar r... inserts all files listed into the archive. If you
>   would like to insert only those of the files you list that are newer
>   than existing members of the same names, use this modifier. The u
>   modifier is allowed only for the operation r (replace). In particular,
>   the combination qu is not allowed, since checking the timestamps would
>   lose any speed advantage from the operation q.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering though if this is possible using cmake. Is there an option for example to give to target_link_libraries...

Comment: I haven't used `cmake` yet, but in `make` you just embed the call to `ar` in one of your rules. Sorry if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: np. upvoated since it adds some insight to the problem ;)

Comment: @IssamT. does it have to be cross-platform? otherwise you can just run this command through cmake

Comment: @m.s. unfortunately yes, it has to be cross-platform.